# ajax call does not succeed

Tags: ajax, json

I have the following code:

```
function processJson(data, i) {
    alert(i);
}

function processChunk(i) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.mplampla.com/idsBook.php?id=8",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert('yooohooooo!!');
            //processJson(data,i);
        },
        error: function() {

            alert('Oops, something went wrong...');
        }

    });
}
```

But it does not succeed and always shows the alert of the error callback! What am I doing wrong? The link is ok when I hit it in the browser... any idea?

Comment: Is this the actual url? It sends 404. Also what do you see in your javascript developer toolbar? Is the AJAX request sent? What does the server respond with?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an absolute URI, odds are that you are violating the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and don't have permission from [CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors) to do so (and since you are specifying JSON, you clearly aren't using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to work around the limitation).

Alternatively, as @Darin Dimitrov points out, your URI resolves to a 404 error which would also cause a failure state for the Ajax call.

… it would help if you looked at your JS console and told us what errors you received though.

Comment: "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."
i run chrome with: chrome.exe --disable-web-security on win 7